# I have damaged my boot drive and lost my system & recovery partitions. And yet, I can still boot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Tonight I made an effort to make my C drive dynamic, which - in hindsight - was ill-advised. I then used EaseUs to move my dynamic drive back into basic. It restarted my PC and performed its boot, and then restarted again and got hung up in the EasUs boot manager. Somehow - after rebooting eight times - it just... booted back into my login screen.

However, to my dismay, my disk is completely messed up.

[image]

I know that my recovery drive is G, while F is the system reserved drive.

[[image: My attempt at recovering my recovery drive]

[[image: More cmd stuff]

[[image: Each folder has contents on it]

[[image: But each appears to be empty (I triple checked for hidden files)]

I do not have a copy of win10 on a USB or an installation media

To reiterate, I can boot and log in. But I fear performing windows updates without my system partition or recovery.

I would like help recovering these two partitions.

Is it possible to repair these partitions with a copy of Windows 10 WITHOUT losing the 250 GB of data on my C drive?

In addition to this, I see that my partitions do not say "Primary partition". Does that matter?

Comment: I would back up the data, check the backup is recoverable, then do a clean install of Windows, reinstall apps and restore the data.

Comment: What I find curious is that I have an EFI partition and yet I was supposedly also using a System reserved partition. As I understand, I only need one and not both. The EFI partition is fine, but should be more than 100mb @RedGrittyBrick

Comment: Do you have in `C:\Windows\System32\Recovery` a file named `Winre.wim` ?

Comment: I agree with the first comment here:  Back up and reinstall Windows.  That is the only way I can see to make this system stable.

Comment: I don't agree : The recovery partition can be recreated. But I need some answers from the poster.

Comment: @harrymc yes winre.wim is in my G drive. I searched for it in my 2nd image. That's what's so strange. I can find winre.wim via cmd but my g drive is empty in the explorer

Comment: Neither of those drive letters in your screenshots is your system partition by the way

Comment: @lane203m - You didn’t say the “system reserve” partition you said “system”, and it wasn’t needlessly, I edited your question so the screenshots were inline which is an improvement. Your off base being upset about an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `winre.wim` file exists, the recovery partition can be restored
as follows:

- Copy the `winre.wim` file to the folder `C:\windows\system32\Recovery`
  (if not already there)
- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Enter the command `diskpart`
- Enter the following commands into `diskpart` to shrink
  partition `C:` by 2048 MB (2 GB) and create in this space a partition
  with the right ID for a recovery partition:

  ```
  list disk
  select disk (DiskNumber from list disk)
  list partition
  select partition (Partitions Number from Drive C:)
  shrink desired=2048
  create partition primary
  format quick fs=ntfs label="winRE"
  set id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
  exit
  ```
- Enter the following command and wait for it to finish:

  ```
  reagentc /enable
  ```

If the `winre.wim` file does not exist, you will need to download
the Windows ISO boot media and extract it from there.

Note that as the recovery partition becomes larger with new
versions of Windows, the recovery partition might need
to be appropriately large.

This and more information can be found in the article
[Windows : create a missing recovery partition](https://www.libe.net/en-windows-recovery-partition).